# rails best practice for accessing related model properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

Is there a specific pattern or patterns that I can research to addresses this situation.

I am trying to come to grips with the best way to access the properties of related models, sometimes distantly related models.

A simple example:

```
class Customer
 has_many :sites
end

class Site
 # Customer is not required
 belongs_to :customer
 has_many :slips
end

class Slip
 belongs_to :site
end
```

I have a report that displays information about specific slips.
In that report I want to refer to the customer's Full Name which is a concatenation of several fields, from a complex method in Customer.

Now I think it is best not to do slip.site.customer.full_name:

1) The linkage is too tight between the models, it seems like I need to know too much about the extended relationships and makes my code brittle.
2) I have to do a nil test, in the case there is no customer for a site.
3) With 2, where do I make the test, surely it is better to have a method like customer_full_name in Site, but if it is only used in Slip and Customer it seems wrong to clutter up Site.

In this example I only have one extended relationship but if I have tickets that also belong to sites and I need the same info there.

Seams best to create a separate helper Class that accepts parameters to generate the required output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using Rails' **delegate** method?
http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

In this case...

```
# slip.rb
# ...

has_one   :customer, through: :site
delegate  :full_name, to: :customer, prefix: :customer, allow_nil: true

# ...
```

To get the associated customer's first name from the slip, use `@slip.customer_first_name`  If no customer exists, this will return `nil`.

Comment: No, and in fact I was not even fully aware of it, I have seen it used in a few places but never understood it's function.